# High performance wcf

Tags: wcf, performance, multithreading, multicore

How do I maximize performance for my wcf service? Is it possible to take
advantage of multicore? or multi-threading?

Thanks!!

Comment: is your communication-performance really your bottleneck?

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. I'm not sure, need to profile. Just wanted to know what I would need to do in case this is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Behavior properties default to the simplest (single threaded) solution, changing them from their default values will give you multiple threading, including self-hosted services.

- [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx)  default is `Single` (single threaded)
- [UseSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.usesynchronizationcontext.aspx) default is `True` (effectively single threaded in UI self hosted scenario)

You may want to also look at [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx) MSDN article gives a starting point on WCF Concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related article, gives some metrics around performance so you can benchmark.

[WCF Service Performance](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/WCF-Service-Performance)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question that is difficult to answer. It will depend on what your service is doing and how it is implemented. But as a general rule of thumb you should avoid long running operations which could monopolize worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you host your WCF service in IIS, then IIS will place each call on it's own thread, giving you the advantage mulitcores on your server.

If you want a single call to run on many threads, then you need to program this yourself in your code. You would only need this if your service is doing a lot of calculations.

Comment: Only if you add the following attribute to the service implementation [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurencyMode.Multiple)].

Comment: Thanks, Shiraz.  My services are self-hosted. How can I place each call in it's own thread for self hosted?